# What is a way to incorporate XML attributes in an array with xpath-like accessor syntax?

Tags: php, hashtable

My favorite XML feature by far is the attribute syntax because it can let you do things like:

```
<order>
   <sku o="1234">
       <warehouse o="PDX">
           <qty>2</qty>
       </warehouse>
       <warehouse o="ATX">
           <qty>4</qty>
       </warehouse>
   </sku>
   <sku o="2345">
       <warehouse o="PHX">
           <qty>5</qty>
       </warehouse>
       <warehouse o="LAX">
           <qty>5</qty>
       </warehouse>
   </sku>
</order>
```

Then you can do this nice xpath syntax to get right at a specific quantity without doing any annoying for-each loops:

`//sku[@o='1234']/warehouse[@o='ATX']/qty`

But I've been trying to map this exact type of syntax without using xpath, for example, just using PHP arrays or such. No luck.

Problem is, this breaks down when you try to have more than two keys (i.e. more than the ordinal key and semantic key), because then in a foreach loop you'll iterated through the item an extra time for each extra key, unless you implement some really annoying logic.

Does anyone have an idea how you could do this in PHP without using xpath or foreach loops, but somehow do it with syntax like:

`$order['sku'=>'1234']['warehouse'=>'PDX']['qty']`

??

The closest I could figure is something like this, although this feels very hack-ish:

```
function addToHashMap($array, $key, $value) {
    array_unshift($array,$value);
    $link = &$array[0];
    $array[$key] = &$link;
    return $array;
}

$order = array();
$order['skus'] = array();
$skus = &$order['skus'];

print_r($order);
print_r($skus);

$skus = addToHashMap($skus,'1234',array('qty'=>'1'));

$skus['1234']['qty'] += 1;

print_r($order);

foreach($skus as $key => $item) {
   if($key < count($skus)/2) continue;
   echo("qty: ".$item['qty']);
}
```

Which returns:

```
Array
(
    [skus] => Array
        (
        )

)
Array
(
)
Array
(
    [skus] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [qty] => 2
                )

            [1234] => Array
                (
                    [qty] => 2
                )

        )

)
qty: 2
```

Comment: The XPATH implementation will use loops in some form or other internally to achieve this as well. And since this type of attribute-value based access is not implemented natively in PHP, you will have to do it yourself – using loops, whether you like it or not.

Comment: @CBroe, if you look at my "hack-ish" example above I already show how can do it without using foreach loops. (My example just has a foreach loop to show that it doesn't return double entries, not that you need a foreach loop to use it.) I mean, PHP does natively support this type of attribute-value access, as my example demonstrates. But I just wondered if there was a better/more accepted way to do it.